# React js - Calling a method from another method

Tags: reactjs

```
    const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'auth_token';

    var api = {

    async removeToken(){
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.removeItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            this.getToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("something went wrong remove token")
        }
    },

    async storeToken(accessToken){
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
            this.getToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("something went wrong store token")
        }
    },

    async getToken(){
        try {
            let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            var parsedToken = JSON.parse(token).auth_token;
            console.log("getToken: " + parsedToken);
            return parsedToken;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("something went wrong gettoken")
            return null;
        }
    },

    getTasks(){
        var url = "http://doit.unicrow.com/api/v1/tasks/";
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Token" + this.getToken()
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
    }
}

module.exports = api;
```

Hi everyone, i am doing a project  with react js and i am having a problem with it. In the above code snippet in getTasks method, I want to call the token value that returns from getToken method . I couldn't do it with using "this". How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using state

maintain a local state as

{
token:""
}
set the token in state as

```
async getToken(){
        try {
            let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);
            var parsedToken = JSON.parse(token).auth_token;
            console.log("getToken: " + parsedToken);
           // return parsedToken;
this.setState({
token:parsedToken
})
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("something went wrong gettoken")
            return null;
        }
    },
```

and in your getTasks method access it from state as

```
   getTasks(){
        var url = "http://doit.unicrow.com/api/v1/tasks/";
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Token" + this.state.token
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you:)